# Dataframe multiplied by respective index value

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a df that contains mostly zeros with the occasional number, I want to multiply every number in the df by its index value divided by 60.

I've tried;

```
for a, b in enumerate(df):
    df[b][a] = df[b][a] * (df.index[a]/60)
```

For example, if the df is;

```
Index    A    B    C    D
1000        0    0    0    0
2000        0    0    4    0
3000        0    0    0    0
4000        0    2    0    0
5000        0    0    0    0
6000        0    0    4    0
```

Then the output should be;

```
Index    A    B    C    D
1000     0    0    0    0
2000     0    0    33.33    0
3000     0    0    0    0
4000     0    133.33    0    0
5000     0    0    0    0
6000     0    0    400    0
```

Where am I going wrong? Any help is really appreciatted, thanks!

**UPDATE**

I ended up using;

```
for c in df_trq.columns[1:]:
    df_trq[c] = (df_trq[c] * df_trq.index.values) / 60
```

This worked becuase I had previously set the index values as something else.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, do like this:

```
for c in df.columns[1:]:
    df[c] = (df[c] * df['Index']) / 60

   Index    A           B           C    D
0   1000  0.0    0.000000    0.000000  0.0
1   2000  0.0    0.000000  133.333333  0.0
2   3000  0.0    0.000000    0.000000  0.0
3   4000  0.0  133.333333    0.000000  0.0
4   5000  0.0    0.000000    0.000000  0.0
5   6000  0.0    0.000000  400.000000  0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
(df.index.values[:, np.newaxis] / 60) * df


Out[50]:

     a   b         c
1000 0.0 0.000000  0.000000
2000 0.0 0.000000  133.333333
3000 0.0 0.000000  0.000000
4000 0.0 133.333333 0.000000 
5000 0.0 0.000000 0.000000
6000 0.0 0.000000 400.000000
```

You result is wrong:

6000 * 4 / 60 = 400 not 600

2000 * 2 /60 = 133.33 not 33.33